# Dynamically named local variables, for loading modules

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to set a local variable (i.e. `var x = 1`) with a dynamic name, like we can for object properties (i.e. `o["prefix:" + x]`)?

For example, I have a CommonJS module and load multiple components from it into individual local variables for convenient access:

```
var module = require("module") // returns object like {a, b, c}
var a = module.a;
var b = module.b;
var c = module.c;
```

I would like to be able to do this in one line - setting local variables for each of the module's properties.

One way of doing it would be something like:

```
Object.assign(local_variable_object, require("module"));
```

where `local_variable_object` is an object with keys as the variable names. If I only want to import part of the module, I could apply a filtering function to the results of `require()`.

I realize that I could probably use `eval`, but that needlessly kills the V8 optimizing compiler because it should be known at optimization time what these variables are and whether or not they're valid.

Comment: No, there's no way to convert your object to local variables without using eval or preferably just doing what you're doing!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In ES5 there's no way to reliably do this without `eval` and outside of the global scope, with `window[varname]`.

## ES2015 pattern matching

ES6 adds [*pattern matching*](http://dmitrysoshnikov.com/notes/pattern-matching/) to the language which allows you to do [*destructuring assignments*](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/05/es6-in-depth-destructuring/).

#### Example:

```
var { a, b, c } = require("module");
```

is equivalent to your inital example (and is how Babel's [ES2015-destructuring](http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-es2015-destructuring/) plugin transpiles it to ES5):

```
var module = require("module");
var a = module.a;
var b = module.b;
var c = module.c;
```

## Native ES5 workaround

There is a workaround for ES5 which is to define your own "local scope" object in your functions, and then use that like you would a normal object.

#### Example:

```
function () {
    "use strict";
    var l = {};
    var a = "someletter";
    l[a] = "A";
    console.log(l.someletter);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is basically what I'm looking for. Yes, it does require me to explicitly state the names in the local context, but not doing so leads to bad, obfuscated code. I hope this gets implemented soon across browsers!

Comment: Well it will be some time before you can deploy native ES2015 code to browsers, personally I'm too impatient to wait so now I write ES2015 transpiled to ES5 with Babel in all my projects.